# Class instance seems to be reset when using Kotlin and Spring Boot dependency injection

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-restcontroller

I am creating/modifying an existing application using Kotlin with Spring Boot. I have annotated a class with `@RestController`, and am using `@Resource` to inject the handler for the class as a dependency.

However, while handling an incoming request, class instance variables seem to get lost. When handling a request, I call `prepare` immediately before `handleRequest`, setting the `objectId` and `accessId` path parameters as class variables of the `FileStreamRequestHandler` class instance. When I step through with a debugger, I know that this is successful, and that an instance of `FileStreamRequestHandler` with appropriately set class variables has been returned.

*However, when `handleRequest` gets called in `Stream`, an error gets thrown that the `lateinit var objectId` has not yet been initialized.*

In the debugger I can see that the instance of `FileStreamRequestHandler` being used changes from:

`{FileStreamRequestHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$feded921@15374}"org.motrpac.drs.handler.FileStreamRequestHandler@73c6c4a6'` in the `prepare` method

to:

`{FileStreamRequestHandler@15466} org.motrpac.drs.handler.FileStreamRequestHandler@374a143` in the `handleRequest` method

This seems to occur only with this one class, as I have other `RestController`s and corresponding handlers with a similar layout that work perfectly fine.

**Stream.kt**

```kotlin
package org.example.controller

import org.example.logging.LoggingUtil
import org.example.handler.FileStreamRequestHandler
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import javax.annotation.Resource
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

/**
 * Stream handler, enables client to access bytes for files on the server machine that the client
 * doesn't have direct access to
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stream")
class Stream {
    @Resource(name = "fileStreamRequestHandler")
    private lateinit var fileStreamRequestHandler: FileStreamRequestHandler

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var loggingUtil: LoggingUtil

    /**
     * Stream file bytes for the requested object and access id
     *
     * @param objectId the object identifier
     * @param accessId the access identifier
     * @param response Spring HttpServletResponse
     */
    @GetMapping(path = ["/{object_id:.+}/{access_id:.+}"])
    fun streamFile(
        @PathVariable(name = "object_id") objectId: String,
        @PathVariable(name = "access_id") accessId: String,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
    ) {
        loggingUtil.debug(
            "Public API request: local file streaming. id='$objectId', access id='$accessId'",
        )
        fileStreamRequestHandler.prepare(objectId, accessId, response).handleRequest()
    }
}
```

**FileStreamRequestHandler**

```kotlin
package org.example.handler

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.example.cache.AccessCache
import org.example.exception.ResourceNotFoundException
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.IOException
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

/**
 * Enables handling logic for the streaming endpoint, allows files stored on the service's file
 * system to be streamed over the API
 */
open class FileStreamRequestHandler(private val accessCache: AccessCache) : RequestHandler<Unit> {
    private lateinit var objectId: String
    private lateinit var accessId: String
    private lateinit var response: HttpServletResponse

    /**
     * Prepares the request handler with input params from the controller function
     *
     * @param objectId Object identifier
     * @param accessId access identifier
     * @param response low-level Spring response object handling file streaming
     * @return the prepared request handler
     */
    fun prepare(
        objectId: String,
        accessId: String,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
    ): FileStreamRequestHandler {
        this.objectId = objectId
        this.accessId = accessId
        this.response = response
        return this
    }

    /** Streams the file contents referenced by the provided object id and access id to client */
    override fun handleRequest() {
        // look up the access cache to see if a valid set of object id and
        // access id was provided
        val cacheItem =
            accessCache[objectId, accessId]
                ?: throw ResourceNotFoundException("invalid access_id/object_id")
        try {
            // Open file input stream
            val inputStream = FileInputStream(cacheItem.objectPath!!)

            // Set Response headers
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment")
            if (cacheItem.mimeType != null) {
                response.contentType = cacheItem.mimeType
            }

            // copy file input stream to response's output stream
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.outputStream)
            response.flushBuffer()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream")
        }
    }
}
```

**SpringAppConfig.kt**

```kotlin
package org.example.app

import org.example.cache.AccessCache
import org.example.handler.FileStreamRequestHandler
import org.example.logging.LoggingUtil
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.RequestScope
import java.io.Serializable

/**
 * Contains Spring bean definitions that are to be loaded for the service
 */
@Configuration
class SpringAppConfig {

    /**
     * Get new request handler facilitating streaming of a local file over http(s)
     *
     * @param accessCache the access cache singleton storing object_id and access_id mappings
     * @return streaming request handler
     */
    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    fun fileStreamRequestHandler(@Autowired accessCache: AccessCache): FileStreamRequestHandler {
        return FileStreamRequestHandler(accessCache)
    }

    /**
     * Get cache singleton, storing object_id and access_id mappings
     *
     * @return object_id, access_id cache
     */
    @Bean
    fun accessCache(): AccessCache {
        return AccessCache()
    }
}
```

I have tried inlining the entire `handleRequest` into the `Stream` class, however, the `access_id` variable seems to disappear as well.

When I step through the debugger, it seems that Spring is calling a `MethodProxy`, but it does this with the other endpoints and handlers as well without losing any class variables, so I am at a loss for what is happening.